# Wildcard character

Tags: regex, r, wildcard

I've a dataframe, and I'm trying to select columns with certain properties in the name.

One example (of many) is I want to select columns called `"t*_b**"` where `*` would be a wildcard character. This would select columns with names t1_b2, t2_b2, t3_b2 and t4_b2 (as well as several others like t1_b13, t2_b13 etc.).

If there is such a wildcard character I could use, I know that I could just use the following command:

```
grep("t*_b", names(df))
```

As opposed to doing:

```
c(grep("t1_b", names(df)), grep("t2_b", names(df)), grep("t3_b", names(df)), grep("t4_b", names(df)))
```

which is messier and harder to read.

**Update:** the first comment has resolved my issue. I don't have any real need for any further input, thanks for the help!

Comment: `grep("t._b", names(df))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard 'character' in regular expressions is a `.`. As such, you could do

```
grep("t._b", names(df))
```